# How to set delay input in MATLAB Neural Network toolbox for system identification?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am using NN to identification a system. Since I assume there is delayed input, I want to include some data which with different latency to the NN. Does MATLAB NN toolbox has built in function to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for timedelaynet

### From Matlab documentation

timedelaynet

Time delay neural network 
Syntax

timedelaynet(inputDelays,hiddenSizes,trainFcn)

Description

Time delay networks are similar to feedforward networks, except that the input weight has a tap delay line associated with it. This allows the network to have a finite dynamic response to time series input data. This network is also similar to the distributed delay neural network (distdelaynet), which has delays on the layer weights in addition to the input weight.

timedelaynet(inputDelays,hiddenSizes,trainFcn) takes these arguments, inputDelays

Row vector of increasing 0 or positive delays (default = 1:2)hiddenSizes

Row vector of one or more hidden layer sizes (default = 10)trainFcn

Training function (default = 'trainlm')

and returns a time delay neural network